# How do we can sort files with neither sort nor ls in bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, unix

How do we can sort files | entries in a directory without using sort command or ls command in bash scripting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How about using Perl then? `perl -wle "print for sort glob shift" *` - in other words, your question doesn't make much sense. Is this homework?

Comment: @Corion I want another way to sort without using predefined Commands..
Yeah i'm working on a small project.

Comment: @Yassine - I think `bash` is the wrong tool to use for that. If you're using `bash`, why don't you want to use `ls` or `sort` ? You will need to add more motivation to your question.

Comment: FWIW, this question makes sense to me.  Using `ls` or `sort` to sort filenames is difficult to do reliably, and is often unnecessary.  If you only need a simple lexical sort by name, globbing is often the best option.  If the number of files is very large, appropriate use of `find` and `sort` may be a better option.  `ls` is almost never the right tool to use.  See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: What i want @Corion is make a project without using 'sort' and 'ls'. For example I substitute them with condition statements and loops..

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see a reason in your requirements. However, here you go:

Bash's globs expand in a sorted way. To print the result of globbing, you can use `printf` .

```
printf %s\\n *
```

You can change the locale to adjust the sorting.

```
prompt$ (export LC_ALL=C; printf %s\\n *)
A
B
a
ab
prompt$ (export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; printf %s\\n *)
a
A
ab
B
```

Comment: it's for academical practices ..